# Python3 insert jsonb array into Postgresql 9.5

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Really need some helps here. I have a column as jsonb[] in Postgresql 9.5.
Let's say I have a list called history in Python. It looks like this [{'name': 'A'},{'name': 'B'},{'name': 'C'}]. After using json.dumps(history). It will be looks like [{"name": "A"},{"name": "B"},{"name": "C"}].

My sql is: `sql = ("INSERT INTO tableA (history_column) VALUES (%s, %s) WHERE tableA.id = %s")`
`connection.cursor().execute(sql, json.dumps(history), id)`

The problem I have here is I cannot insert `json.dumps(history)`. The Postgresql shows an error message:

`'[{"name":...

"[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.`

[image]

I think json.dumps somehow just doesn't work very well with jsonb array. I don't know if there is a way to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. The potential solution is to write a python script to convert the query to `update tableName set columnName = ARRAY['{"name":"A"}'::jsonb, '{"name": "A"}'::jsonb] where id = %s;`
This may not be a good solution but it works for now.